# Android VideoView picture doesn't update wile playing

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I've coded up apps using VideoView and MediaPlayer and both had the same behavior. I'm currently using the code example [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video). The problem I'm having is that the video doesn't play back continuously. The slider in the MediaController is moving but the picture doesn't change. If I manually drag the slider the picture will change like it should.

I'm using an mp4 file loaded from the sdcard with a SDK 2.3.1 emulator device.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You usually cannot test video playback applications on the Android emulator, as it is too slow, except on very powerful host PCs. Please test video playback applications on an Android device.